# Merge array keys into one array

Tags: php

So i maybe have a simple question. but i just can't figure out how to solve this.
I got 1 array that looks like this.

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

)
1
```

is it possible to merge the two keys into 1 key. and merge it into like this.

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )


)
1
```

much thanks

Comment: how about `array_merge($array[0], $array[1])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can user php array_merge function like this:

```
$final_array = array();
foreach ($your_array as $a){
    $final_array = array_merge($final_array,$a);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($final_array);
die;
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution for unknown number of subarrays is:

```
$ar = array(array(1,3), array(2,4), array(5));
$r = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $ar);
print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = Array
(
    '0' => Array
        (
            '0' => 1,
            '1' => 2
        ),

    '1' => Array
        (
            '0' => 3
        )

);
$result = array();
foreach($array as $_array)
{
    foreach($_array as $__array)
    {
        $result[] = $__array;
    }    
}    

print_r($result);
```